# How to reinitailize the object of a viewmodel in Dependeny injection in xamarin forms?

Tags: dependency-injection, xamarin.forms, autofac

I am using Autofac dependecy injection in my xamarin forms project. I created a constructor and its viewmodel. And then register it in a container of Autofac. Its working fine at first. But when user comes on the page it shows the same values that I saved last time in properties. I want to reinitialize the object of viewmodel. Here is my code :

Interface:

```
     public ILoadViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
     {
     }
```

ViewModel:

```
     public class LoadViewModel : ViewModelBase, ILoadViewModel
{
    private INavigationService navigationService;
    public string Username { get ; set ; }
    public LoadRouteViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        this.navigationService = navigationService;

    }
```

Xaml.cs :

```
     viewModel = AppContainer.Container.Resolve<ILoadViewModel>();
```

At first it initialize the viewmodel. But when I open the page next time . It shows the same Username value that I stored last time.

How I can reinitailize it.

Comment: That should not happen by default. How did you register the ViewModel in Autofac?

Comment: builder.RegisterType<LoadRouteViewModel>()
           .As<ILoadRouteViewModel>();
           .SingleInstance();

Comment: I posted an answer, if you find it helpful please accept and upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how the `ViewModel` is registered with `Autofac` you may experience different outcome. If you defined the scope to be `SingleInstance()` (single instance scope) then the container will resolve **the same instance** on every `Resolve`. If your intent is to get a new instance on each `Resolve` (per dependency scope), you should not define any lifetime scope, so simply remove the `.SingleInstance()`:

```
builder.RegisterType<LoadRouteViewModel>().As<ILoadRouteViewModel>();
```

You can read more about lifetime scopes [here](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html).

P.S.: Beside that, it is a good practice to mark the injected instances as `readonly`.